OpenAPI: Reference from component schema in requestBody and response
Is it possible to reference a property of an object in requestBody or response in OpenAPI?
openapi: '3.0.2'
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      summary: login a user
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
# What I would like to do:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/User/fullName' 
# but appending "/fullName" throws error
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
# What I would like to do:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/User/Id' 
# but appending "/Id" throws error

components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id: 
          type: string
          format: uuid
        fullName:
          type: string


Just to clarify - your current design means the request body will be just a string like "John Smith" (in quotes) rather than a JSON object, and the response body will also be just a string "d9d71eb2-b9cb-4c98-961c-ebc0495635c4" (in quotes). Is this what you want? Or do you want to send / return JSON objects like {"fullName": "John Smith"} and {"id": "d9d71eb2-b9cb-4c98-961c-ebc0495635c4"}?

Thanks for the clarification. I actually intended to send and return those values as JSON objects.

Thanks to Helen and Jeremy I got it:
openapi: '3.0.2'
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      summary: login a user
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json: 
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                fullName:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/User/properties/fullName'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json: 
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  id: 
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/User/properties/id'
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id: 
          type: string
          format: uuid
        fullName:
          type: string



You missed the properties keyword in your path
openapi: '3.0.2'
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      summary: login a user
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json: // should be `text/plain` if you want to return the string value directly
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/User/properties/fullName'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json: // should be `text/plain` if you want to return the string value directly
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/User/properties/id'
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id: 
          type: string
          format: uuid
        fullName:
          type: string


to Helen's point, the content-type: application/json is not the correct media type for the schema you are trying to reference. the output would be text/plain rather than JSON.
